# How To Change target paths for thousands of products at once

Tags: magento-1.7

I am using Magento 1.7.1 and find that magento has automatically added ugly urls like www.afd.com/catalog/product/view/id/2728/name.html.

When I go into catalog > URL Rewrite, I see the target paths for all my products listed in the above totally unfriendly way with id numbers displaying.

How do I fix this en masse?

Thanks.
-TM

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it by using a .csv file. You can create a php file which will run outside your project and do the expected changes via a csv file. Also hopes this will help to grab an idea. `http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-url-rewrites/`

Answer (score 0):

Refresh all indexes in magento, here is instrucion http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/magento/102-customizing-magento/how-to-reindex-your-magento-website, then flush all cache. Then magento should use Url Rewrites. If doesn't work make sure that you heve proper settings in

```
System->Configuration->Web->Search Engine Optimization
```